# Header location does not redirect

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a controller

```
@RestController
public class MessageRestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/sendMessage")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendMessage(
            @RequestParam String username,
            UriComponentsBuilder builder
    ) {
        UriComponents components = builder.path("/profile/{username}").buildAndExpand(username);
        System.out.println("LinK: " + components);

        return ResponseEntity.created(components.toUri()).build();
    }
}
```

Which is the POST method and after the call should in the header of the site in location add a value for example

```
http://localhost:8080/profile/hereIsSomeUsername
```

Then it should redirect to the given address. Still, there is no reaction. Location is set https://zapodaj.net/102d5f0d98e58.png.html , but does not redirect.

Comment: more info is needed. how are you calling this sendMessage endpoint? through ajax call? it's an html form post?

Comment: Called by ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can add *HttpServletResponse* object to your Controller method parameters and Spring will do the rest to make sure that it's correctly wired.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/sendMessage") 
public ResponseEntity<?> sendMessage( 
        @RequestParam String username,
        UriComponentsBuilder builder,
        HttpServletResponse response
){
//...
}
```

Then, you can send redirect to desired URL:

```
response.sendRedirect(components.toUri());
```

And remember to handle IOException.

After that's done, your request will be redirected to the selected URL and you will get a response from new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Being an ajax call, there is nothing you can do on server-side to make the main site location to change (by main site i understand you are talking about the site opened on your browser). The redirect you will receive will affect your ajax call to be redirected there, not the "browser site".

Your client-side code will need to react on server-side response and change the location of your current page.